# max and min of a function $f(x,y)$

Tags: real-analysis

I consider the function $f(x,y)=e^{9(x+y)}-2(x+y)$. I study the gradient of this function and I find as critical points a line $(t,-t+{{1}\over{9}} \ln{{2}\over{9}})$ for $t \in \mathbb{R}$. How can I determinate global and local max and min?

Comment: Hey. Can you elaborate (by editing your post) what you mean by "nature of these points"?

Comment: Can i use Taylor to study the behavior near these points?